# Position von "mir" in "Es ist mir nicht schwer, vorzustellen"

Tags: grammar, word-order

> (a) Es ist mir nicht schwer, vorzustellen, wie viel Schwierigkeit er während seiner Krankheit gehabt haben muss.
>
> (b) Es ist nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen, wie viel Schwierigkeit er während seiner Krankheit gehabt haben muss.

Welche Position von "mir" ist richtig? Oder sind beide richtig, aber mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide sind falsch!

> **Ich** kann **mir** etwas vorstellen …
>
> **Man** kann **sich** etwas vorstellen …
>
> **Es** ist nicht schwer, **sich** etwas vorzustellen …

'Schwer' in (a) regiert keine Ergänzung im Dativ wie z. B. 'egal' (Es ist '*mir*' egal …)

Bei (b) hast Du einen Nebensatz, der nicht dasselbe Subjekt wie der Hauptsatz hat, also funktioniert beim Verb 'vorstellen' die Infinitiv-Konstruktion nicht! Du könntest also nur Folgendes sagen:

> **Es** ist nicht schwer, dass **ich** mir vorstelle …

oder besser noch:

> **Ich** kann **mir** gut vorstellen, dass er …

Eine weitere Möglichkeiten wären dann noch:

> Es fällt **mir** nicht schwer, **mir** vorzustellen …

Hier wird beim Verb 'fallen' die Aufgabe der normalerweise notwendigen Übereinstimmung zwischen den beiden Subjekten des Haupt- und Nebensatzes auf das Objekt 'mir' des Hauptsatzes übertragen. Man muss also nicht sagen:

> Es fällt **mir** nicht schwer, dass ich **mir** vorstelle …

Mehr generell könntest du dann natürlich auch sagen:

> Es fällt **einem** nicht schwer, **sich** vorzustellen …

Comment: Funktioniert dann "Es **ist** **mir** nicht schwer, **mir** vorzustellen ..."?

Comment: Ich hab die Antwort nochmal editiert, sorry! Du findest die Lösung ganz am Anfang... - ***'Schwer' in (a) regiert keine Ergänzung...***

Comment: "Es ist nicht schwer für mich, mir vorzustellen ..." wäre näher am originalen Vorschlag, klingt meiner Meinung nach natürlicher als "Es ist nicht schwer, dass ich mir vorstelle ..." und gleichzeitig nicht so geschwollen (in gesprochener Sprache) wie "Es fällt mir nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen ...".

Comment: @mramosch Ich habe das nicht wirklich verstanden. Zum Beispiel: "Es ist mir kalt", "Die Hausaufgabe ist ihm schwer". Was ist daran falsch?

Comment: @boaten: Deutsch hat ***eine*** sehr eigenwillige Satzkonstruktion, und genau die sprichst du hier an. 'Es' wird nicht wirklich als vollwertiges Subjekt angesehen (das musst du nachschlagen) - du kannst es auch weglassen! '*Mir ist schlecht*' - kein Nominativ ;-) -> Der Dativ 'mir' erzeugt fast das Gefühl der Hauptakteur zu sein, das Subjekt! '**Hausaufgabe**' ist ein richtiges Subjekt im Nominativ - '**ist**' Verb - '**schwer**' Prädikativum - Dieses '**Prädikativum**'kann '*manchmal*' eine Ergänzung haben -> z.B. bei '**egal**' - Das ist (**mir**) '*egal*' -> bei '**schwer**' aber nicht...

Answer (score 1):

> Es ist mir nicht schwer ...

Das ist nicht möglich. Das *schwer sein* verlangt kein *mir* (im Gegensatz zu *möglich*). Damit scheidet Kandidat (a) aus.

> Es ist nicht schwer, ...

Das ist ein gültiger Satz, der für sich allein stehen kann. Der Nebensatz hängt die Erklärung an, was nicht schwer ist:

Man könnte beispielsweise erklären:

> Es ist nicht schwer, mir zu schreiben.

Die Verwendung von:

> Es ist nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen, wie viel ...

suggeriert aber, dass jemand mir etwas vorstellen möchte (im Sinne von Bekanntschaft herbeiführen).

Deswegen nimmt man im Hauptsatz noch die Information hinzu, für wen es nicht schwer ist (also *für mich*), und schon bekommt *vorstellen* die Bedeutung von *vergegenwärtigen* und kann nicht mit *bekanntmachen* verwechselt werden:

> Es ist nicht schwer für mich, mir vorzustellen, wie viel Schwierigkeiten er während seiner Krankheit gehabt haben muss.

(Es ist auch besser, "wie viel Schwierigkeiten" zu schreiben. Bei unbekannten Mengen, die abzählbar sind, verwendet man den Plural.)

Comment: *wieviel* kann ich [im Duden](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/wieviel) nicht finden. Sollte man dann "wie viele Schwierigkeiten" sagen?

Comment: ja richtig. Es ist furchtbar, dass es nach der Neuen dt. Rechtschreibung getrennt geschrieben wird. Das ist, als ob man *deswegen* oder *einwandfrei* wieder trennen würde.

Answer (score -1):

Das Verb „vorstellen“ ist reflexiv, so dass es es hier ein „mir“ benötigt, weshalb der erste Satz falsch ist. Es muss also heißen:

> ..., mir vorzustellen, ...

Formulieren wir das ganze weniger persönlich, ist möglich:

> Es ist nicht schwer, sich vorzustellen, ...

Es geht aber auch nicht:

> *** Es ist nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen, ...

Hier müssen wir auch den ersten Teil personalisieren, in die folgende Richtung:

> *** Es ist mir nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen, ...

Allerdings ist „es ist mir schwer“ keine mögliche Konstruktion. Möglich sind zum Beispiel die folgenden:

> Es fällt mir nicht schwer, mir vorzustellen, ...
>
> Es ist nicht schwer für mich, mir vorzustellen, ...