# "Wie viel Schwierigkeiten": Wann und ob das geht?

Tags: grammar, noun, adjective-ending

In einer Antwort zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25342/position-von-mir-in-es-ist-mir-nicht-schwer-vorzustellen) wird der Ausdruck

> wie viel Schwierigkeiten

verwendet. Meine Reaktion war, dass es doch

> wie viele Schwierigkeiten

oder

> wie viel Schwierigkeit

sein sollte, was auch durch [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23109/when-to-use-wie-viel-and-when-wie-viele) und [diese](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5419/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-wieviel-und-wie-viel/5421#5421) Frage bestätigt ist. Aber eine Google-Suche ergibt ziemlich viele Ergebnisse für ["wie viel Schwierigkeiten"](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22wie+viel+schwierigkeiten%22), darunter auch mehrere Bücher. Ich bin mir nicht mehr sicher, ob es wirklich falsch ist.

Ist der Ausdruck grammatikalisch richtig? Gibt es Situationen, in denen man "wie viel" mit Pluralnomen verwenden kann?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laut Nachschlagewerken zur deutschen Sprache ist beides völlig korrekt.

Vermutlich befinden wir uns in einer Übergangsphase zwischen zwei Beugungsschemata für Bestimmungswörter wie *viel* oder *wie viel*. Wenn vorher das eine Beugungsschema gilt und hundert Jahre später das andere, müssen dazwischen zeitweise Inkonsistenzen und Unsicherheiten bestanden haben. Luther, Goethe und selbst Karl May hat noch Wörter anders dekliniert, als wir das heute tun. (Bei Karl May wird z.B. häufiger der Dativ mit *-e* markiert: "mit lautem Flügelschlage".)

Insbesondere ist hier ganz offensichtlich die Zusammensetzung *wie viel[e]* ein Vorreiter, der die allgemeine Entwicklung vorweg nimmt. Denn das *e* darf man (bisher) nur in Verbindung mit *wie* weglassen.

Manche Leute finden subtile Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Varianten, andere sehen andere Unterschiede, viele empfinden beide als völlig gleichwertig, und wieder andere finden nur eine korrekt, ohne sich dabei aber über die andere aufzuregen. Das ist alles völlig normal. So sieht der Sprachwandel nun mal aus, wenn man ihn während der Tat ertappt.

Ich persönlich finde übrigens *wie viel* im Fall von *Schwierigkeiten* die etwas bessere Variante. Denn die Antwort "Es sind drei Schwierigkeiten" würde die meisten verblüffen, weil man Schwierigkeiten trotz des Plurals normalerweise nicht zählt sondern eher als etwas Unzählbares behandelt. Das heißt natürlich nicht, dass *Schwierigkeiten* kein Plural wäre. Aber es heißt, dass eine Form, die eher nach Singular aussieht, in diesem Fall ein bisschen besser passt. "Wie viel Schwierigkeiten" und "Wie viel Finger" sind beide richtig, aber Ersteres ist stilistisch m.E. besser als "Wie viele Schwierigkeiten", und Letzteres ist stilistisch schlechter als "Wie viele Finger".

Das ist eine Momentaufnahme aus dem Sprachwandel. Vor dreißig Jahren hätte ich das sicher anders gesehen. In dreißig Jahren werde ich es anders sehen. Wer älter ist als ich, wird diese Entwicklungen langsamer nachvollziehen als ich, und wer jünger ist, schneller.

### PS: Statistik

Nachdem Takkat ein interessantes Diagramm aus Googles n-Gramm-Suche aufgebracht hat, habe ich mich etwas systematischer mit Statistiken zur Frage beschäftigt. Leider wird es schnell sehr kompliziert und unübersichtlich, wenn man es richtig macht. Deshalb beschreibe ich hier schrittweise, wie ich zu meinem Ansatz gekommen bin.

**Es kommt entscheidend auf das Fragewort *wie* an.** Normalerweise muss es "viele Schwierigkeiten" heißen. Erst mit dem Fragewort *wie* davor haben wir die Wahl zwischen "wie viele Schwierigkeiten" und "wie viel Schwierigkeiten". Ich vermute, das ist der Grund, warum das ungebeugte *wieviel* früher zusammengeschrieben wurde.

***Wie* kommt vor *viel* auch in einer ganz anderen Bedeutung vor.** Wir müssen eigentlich die beiden folgenden Fälle unterscheiden:

> Ich will wissen, wie viel[e] Schwierigkeiten du hattest. Also: Wie viel[e] Schwierigkeiten hattest du?
>
> Wie viele Schwierigkeiten in diesem Bereich zeigen, ... [Hier dürfte jeder Muttersprachler erkennen, dass *viel* falsch ist.]

Bei der Frage interessiert uns nur der erste Fall. Es ist aber praktisch unmöglich, die beiden in einer Suche zu trennen.

Ob *wie viel[e]* am Satzanfang steht oder nicht, sollte dagegen eigentlich keinen Unterschied machen. Im Vorgriff auf die Ergebnisse: Das ist falsch!

**Groß- und Kleinschreibung beachten.** Anders als die gewöhnlichen Suchfunktionen unterscheidet der n-gram-Viewer pedantisch zwischen Groß- und Kleinschreibung. Wenn wir beispielsweise nach "wieviel" suchen, ist "Wieviel" nicht dabei, und umgekehrt! Das ist im Folgenden immer zu beachten.

**Rechtschreibregeln vor 1998.** Vor der ersten Rechtschreibreform wurde die ungebeugte Variante von *wie viel* noch als *wieviel* in einem Wort geschrieben: "wieviel Schwierigkeiten". Daneben war es aber auch damals schon möglich, zu der Angabe *viele Schwierigkeiten* mit *wie* eine Präzisierung anzufordern: "wie (viele Schwierigkeiten)". Allerdings nur bei Pluralen; vor unzählbaren Substantiven wie *Wasser* wurde *wieviel* immer zusammengeschrieben, obwohl es vielleicht logischer gewesen wäre, das je nach Bedeutung zu unterschiedlich zu handhaben. (In diesem Punkt war die alte Rechtschreibung also durchaus chaotischer.)

> Wie bereits *so viele, wie viele* wird jetzt auch *so viel, wie viel* geschrieben [(Sprachreport, Extra-Ausgabe 1998)](http://pub.ids-mannheim.de/laufend/sprachreport/pdf/sr98-extra.pdf)

Der Google-Korpus zeigt, dass das am Satzanfang auch immer richtig gemacht wurde. Die falschen Varianten kamen mit großem *W* praktisch nicht vor. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wieviele+Schwierigkeiten%2CWie+viel+Schwierigkeiten&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20) Allerdings sind auch die richtigen Varianten am Satzanfang sehr selten, vermutlich weil in den überrepräsentierten wissenschaftlichen Texten selten direkte Fragen gestellt werden.

Mit kleinem *w* gab es aber erhebliche Unsicherheiten, die wohl diesen Punkt der Reform motiviert haben dürften. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wieviele+Schwierigkeiten%2Fwie+viele+Schwierigkeiten%2Cwie+viel+Schwierigkeiten%2Fwieviel+Schwierigkeiten&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20&smoothing=10)

Es bietet sich an, in einem ersten Schritt nur Daten bis 1997 zu benutzen, weil das einfacher ist. In einem zweiten Schritt können wir dann die neue Rechtschreibung als Variante hinzufügen und auch die neuesten Daten berücksichtigen.

**Variantenvergleich vor der Rechtschreibreform.** Es geht um die Frage, ob es natürlicher ist, "Wie viele Schwierigkeiten?" zu fragen oder"Wieviel Schwierigkeiten?". Bedeutungsunterschiede (egal ob subtil oder nicht) können wir mit dem n-gram-Viewer natürlich nicht erfassen, deshalb ist eine Aussage darüber nicht möglich.

Tatsächlich können wir noch nicht mal die komplett andere Bedeutung von *wie* in "Wie viele Schwierigkeiten in diesem Bereich zeigen" ausschließen. Deshalb wird bei allen Ergebnissen die gebeugte Variante *wie viele* eigentlich zu gut wegkommen.

Der Einfachheit halber werde ich hier zunächst nur die Varianten berücksichtigen, die auch vor der Rechtschreibreform schon richtig waren. Bei den falsch geschriebenen ist sowieso nicht ganz klar, worin der Fehler denn nun besteht: Ist bei "wieviele" die Zusammenschreibung falsch ("wie viele" gemeint) oder die Beugung ("wieviel" gemeint). Analog für das vor der Reform falsche "wie viel". Außerdem kann es auch methodisch Sinn ergeben, Quellen mit falscher Rechtschreibung auszuschließen, wenn man an gutem Sprachgebrauch interessiert ist.

- Rohe Kurven von "Wieviel Schwierigkeiten" und "Wie viele Schwierigkeiten". [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wieviel+Schwierigkeiten%2CWie+viele+Schwierigkeiten&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20&smoothing=3)
- Rohe Kurven von "wieviel Schwierigkeiten" und "wie viele Schwierigkeiten". [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wieviel+Schwierigkeiten%2Cwie+viele+Schwierigkeiten&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20&smoothing=3)
- Relative Anteile am Satzanfang. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wieviel+Schwierigkeiten%2F((Wieviel+Schwierigkeiten)%2B(Wie+viele+Schwierigkeiten))%2CWie+viele+Schwierigkeiten%2F((Wieviel+Schwierigkeiten)%2B(Wie+viele+Schwierigkeiten))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20
- Relative Anteile im Satzinneren. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wieviel+Schwierigkeiten%2F((wieviel+Schwierigkeiten)%2B(wie+viele+Schwierigkeiten))%2Cwie+viele+Schwierigkeiten%2F((wieviel+Schwierigkeiten)%2B(wie+viele+Schwierigkeiten))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20

Leider bringen die Klammern in den letzten beiden URLs den Markup-Parser von StackExchange durcheinander. Aber auch mit den Diagrammen selbst gibt es ein Problem: Die beiden Kurven müssten sich eigentlich jeweils genau zu 100% addieren, aber das ist meist nicht der Fall! Der Fehler ist mathematisch nicht erklärbar und dürfte vermutlich auf Optimierungen bei der Suche zurückgehen, die sich wegen der insgesamt geringen Trefferzahl stark auswirken.

Mein Fazit aus diesen Diagrammen: Beide Varianten sind ungefähr gleich häufig. Wegen großer Schwankungen, die sich aus der insgesamt geringen Trefferzahl ergeben, ist keine Aussage über Trends möglich.

**Variantenvergleich ohne konkretes Substantiv.**

Wenn wir auf das Wort *Schwierigkeiten* verzichten, erhalten wir einfachere Such-Strings und so viele Treffer, dass keine Artefakte durch die Optimierung zu sehen sind. Am besten wäre es, wenn wir statt *Schwierigkeiten* "beliebiges Substantiv im Plural" angeben könnten. Leider werden Singular und Plural in der Datenbank aber nicht automatisch erfasst. Deshalb werden wir ab jetzt nicht mehr nur für *wie viele* unpassende Treffer haben, die wir nicht aussortieren können. Da wir keine unzählbaren Substantive im Singular ausschließen können, hat vielmehr ab jetzt *wieviel* einen starken Vorteil durch den großen Beifang aus Fällen wie "wieviel Wasser", in denen sich die Frage der Variante "wie viele Wasser" erst gar nicht stellt.

Aber immerhin können wir häufige Fälle wie "wieviel mehr" ausschließen, indem wir ein beliebiges Substantiv fordern.

Anmerkung: Ich bin für Anregungen aufgeschlossen, welches konkrete Substantiv womöglich sehr viel häufiger als *Schwierigkeiten* hinter "wieviel" bzw. "wie viele" steht. Das würde sich dann anbieten, um diese Probleme zu lösen.

- Rohe Kurven von "Wieviel *NOUN*" (rot) und "Wie viele *NOUN*" (blau); mit falschen Varianten zum Vergleich. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+_NOUN_%2CWieviel+_NOUN_%2CWieviele+_NOUN_%2CWie+viel+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20)
- Rohe Kurven von "wieviel *NOUN*" (rot) und "wie viele *NOUN*" (blau); mit falschen Varianten zum Vergleich. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+_NOUN_%2Cwieviel+_NOUN_%2Cwieviele+_NOUN_%2Cwie+viel+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20)
- Relative Anteile am Satzanfang. Der Einfachheit halber ohne Berücksichtigung der Falschschreibungen. [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+*NOUN*%2F((Wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(Wieviel+*NOUN*))%2CWieviel+*NOUN*%2F((Wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(Wieviel+*NOUN*))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+_NOUN_%2F((Wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(Wieviel+_NOUN_))%2CWieviel+_NOUN_%2F((Wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(Wieviel+_NOUN_))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20)
- Relative Anteile im Satzinneren. Der Einfachheit halber ohne Berücksichtigung der Falschschreibungen. [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+*NOUN*%2F((wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(wieviel+*NOUN*))%2Cwieviel+*NOUN*%2F((wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(wieviel+*NOUN*))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+_NOUN_%2F((wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(wieviel+_NOUN_))%2Cwieviel+_NOUN_%2F((wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(wieviel+_NOUN_))&year_start=1900&year_end=1997&corpus=20)

Mein Fazit aus diesen Diagrammen: Vor beliebigem Substantiv zeigt sich eine Tendenz zur Bevorzugung der deklinierten Form *wie viele*. Weil wir für beide Varianten gewisse häufige falsche Treffer nicht ausschließen können (die ihrerseits eigenen Trends unterliegen könnten), lassen sich weder über die absolute Höhe der Bevorzugung von *wie viele* noch über Trends genauere und halbwegs gesicherte Aussagen machen. Es sieht aber so aus, als wäre die deklinierte Form gegen Ende etwa doppelt so populär wie die undeklinierte, bei zunehmender Tendenz.

Um das zu überprüfen, könnte man in Google Books in ein paar Zeiträumen nach "wie viele" und "wie viel" suchen und stichprobenartig die Häufigkeit der unerwünschten Treffer ermitteln. Das ist mir aber zu viel Aufwand.

Nur eines scheint sicher: Es gibt einen ganz erheblichen Unterschied zwischen Satzanfang und Satzinnerem! Wichtig wäre es, zu untersuchen, ob dieser Unterschied auch innerhalb der einzelnen Texte des Korpus existiert oder vielmehr dadurch zu Stande kommt, dass verschiedene Textarten (z.B. Roman, Sachbuch, Dissertation) unterschiedliche Präferenzen haben - sowohl in Bezug auf die beiden Varianten als auch in Bezug auf deren Platzierung im Satz. Im letzteren Fall müsste man dann auch bei der Ermittlung von Trends die Textarten getrennt berücksichtigen, weil diese bekanntermaßen im Korpus keine konstanten Anteile haben.

Weil ich keinen sprachlichen Grund für den Unterschied zwischen Satzanfang und Satzinnerem erkennen kann, vermute ich, dass er sich entweder wie beschrieben aus den Textarten ergibt, oder dadurch, dass die unerwünschten Beifänge sich statistisch anders zwischen Satzanfang und Satzinnerem verteilen als die gesuchten Daten.

Wenn z.B. Konstruktionen der Art "Wie viele ... zeigen, ..." besonders am Satzanfang häufig und in letzter Zeit mit zunehmender Tendenz vorkommen sollten, würde das schon mal einige auffällige Unterschiede erklären. Auch das könnte man durch Stichproben abklären.

**Fortschreibung über die Rechtschreibreform hinweg.** Um auch Daten nach der Rechtschreibreform zu berücksichtigen, müssen wir die alte und die neue Rechtschreibung von Hand zusammenfassen. Dadurch zählen wir dann zwangsläufig in den Quellen mit alter Rechtschreibung auch die relativ seltene Falschschreibung *wie viel* mit, weil sie durch die Reform nachträglich legitimiert wird.

- Rohe Kurven von "Wie[ ]viel *NOUN*" (rot) und "Wie viele *NOUN*" (blau); mit falschen Varianten zum Vergleich. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+_NOUN_%2CWieviel+_NOUN_%2BWie+viel+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&corpus=20)
- Rohe Kurven von "wie[ ]viel *NOUN*" (rot) und "wie viele *NOUN*" (blau); mit falschen Varianten zum Vergleich. [(Diagramm)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+_NOUN_%2Cwieviel+_NOUN_%2Bwie+viel+_NOUN_&year_start=1900&corpus=20)
- Relative Anteile am Satzanfang. Der Einfachheit halber ohne Berücksichtigung der Falschschreibung "Wieviele". [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+*NOUN*%2F((Wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(Wieviel+*NOUN*)%2B(Wie+viel+*NOUN*))%2C(Wieviel+*NOUN*%2BWie+viel+*NOUN*)%2F((Wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(Wieviel+*NOUN*)%2B(Wie+viel+*NOUN*))&year_start=1900&corpus=20](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wie+viele+_NOUN_%2F((Wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(Wieviel+_NOUN_)%2B(Wie+viel+_NOUN_))%2C(Wieviel+_NOUN_%2BWie+viel+_NOUN_)%2F((Wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(Wieviel+_NOUN_)%2B(Wie+viel+_NOUN_))&year_start=1900&corpus=20)
- Relative Anteile im Satzinneren. Der Einfachheit halber ohne Berücksichtigung der Falschschreibung "wieviele". [https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+*NOUN*%2F((wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(wieviel+*NOUN*)%2B(wie+viel+*NOUN*))%2C(wieviel+*NOUN*%2Bwie+viel+*NOUN*)%2F((wie+viele+*NOUN*)%2B(wieviel+*NOUN*)%2B(wie+viel+*NOUN*))&year_start=1900&corpus=20](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wie+viele+_NOUN_%2F((wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(wieviel+_NOUN_)%2B(wie+viel+_NOUN_))%2C(wieviel+_NOUN_%2Bwie+viel+_NOUN_)%2F((wie+viele+_NOUN_)%2B(wieviel+_NOUN_)%2B(wie+viel+_NOUN_))&year_start=1900&corpus=20)

Im vorderen Teil bis 1997 unterscheiden sich die Diagramme wie erwartet nicht wesentlich von den früheren. Neu ist die chaotische Situation am Satzanfang, wo es so aussieht, als wären die beiden Varianten jetzt bis auf eine unbedeutende Oszillation dauerhaft genau gleich häufig.

Die plötzliche kleine Zäsur um 1998 im Satzinneren legt den Gedanken nahe, dass womöglich einige Leute angefangen haben, wenn möglich die Variante "wie viele" zu wählen, um das immer noch fremd wirkende "wie viel" zu umgehen. Das könnte dann auch erklären, warum der vorübergehende Anstieg der ungebeugten Variante so schnell in einen ebenfalls nur vorübergehenden Abfall überging.

Aber wie früher gilt: Die Diagramme sind wegen des unerwünschten Beifangs der Suchen und des variablen Anteils verschiedener Textarten im Korpus wahrscheinlich sehr irreführend.

Comment: Kannst Du Deine Funde in Nachschlagewerken referenzieren oder etwas ausführen?

Comment: Ich hab grad selber keins zur Hand. In [dieser Diskussion](http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,76114) hat aber jemand ausgiebig aus dem Duden-Band "Richtiges und gutes Deutsch" zitiert.

Comment: Mein Hauptproblem mit Belegen ist, dass ich auf diese Situation vor relativ kurzer Zeit an Hand eines anderen Bestimmungsworts oder vielleicht auch Adjektivs aufmerksam geworden bin, mich aber nicht mehr erinnern kann, welches das war. Deshalb hab ich jetzt Schwierigkeiten, meine alte Quelle wieder zu finden.

Comment: Ich sehe keine Schwierigkeit darin, Schwierigkeiten zu zählen. Gerade in einer Diskussion müsste man sagen könnnen: "Welche denn, zähl doch mal auf!" Im Gegensatz zu: "Wie viel Wasser kannst Du trinken?"

Comment: Der Gewinner ist: [viele Schwierigkeiten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=viel+Schwierigkeiten%2Cviele+Schwierigkeiten&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cviel%20Schwierigkeiten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cviele%20Schwierigkeiten%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @userunknown: Schwierigkeiten sehe ich da auch nicht. Es geht mir nicht um die binäre Einteilung in die Klassen zählbar und unzählbar sondern um die Platzierung auf der Skala, die durch die beiden Klassen nur unzureichend abgebildet wird. *Schwierigkeiten* ist ein Zweifelsfall, den andere Sprachen evt. anders behandeln würden. Für den Sprachwandel ist das hochgradig relevant, denn an solchen Bruchstellen beginnt die Erosion der alten Regeln.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich hab die Stelle etwas überarbeitet, damit es klarer wird.

Comment: Ich sehe da keinen Fortschritt, sondern unterstreiche meine Kritik: Die Behauptung, dass man Schwierigkeiten normalerweise nicht zählt halte ich für aus der Luft gegriffen und schlicht falsch. "Ich habe viele Schwierigkeiten den Test zu bestehen." "Welche?" "In Frage 2 ... in Frage 7 .. und in den Fragen 8 und 9 ...". Überall wo man willens ist die Schwierigkeiten anzugehen kommt man nicht drum rum diese aufzulisten. Zwar gibt es Ausdrücke wie "ich habe Schwierigkeiten mit dem Feldaufschwung" bei denen eine nähere Analyse vielleicht oft unterbleibt, aber das hebt die anderen Fälle nicht auf ->

Comment: '"Es sind drei Schwierigkeiten" würde die meisten verblüffen, weil man Schwierigkeiten trotz des Plurals normalerweise nicht zählt' Es ist unerheblich, ob man die Schwierigkeiten zählt. Entscheidend ist, dass man sie zählen kann, egal ob es 2 sind oder 279. Unzählbar sind für mich Gemente wie Mehl: "WIe viel Mehl ist noch da?" Mehl ist im Singular. Schwierigkeiten ist dagegen ja unstrittig im Plural - es müsste nach Deiner Logik dann "Wie viel Schwierigkeit" heißen.

Comment: PS: Wenn Du das zu einem Buch ausbauen willst, dann würde ich darauf achten die Graphen so zu machen, dass die Farbcodierung einheitlich ist, also etwa immer rot für die Form mit e. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, "wie viel Schwierigkeiten" is grammatikalisch falsch (richtig ist "wieviele Schwierigkeiten". Für mich hört sich das einfach falsch an. Es ist aber nur ein kleiner Fehler und kann sich leicht einschleichen.